# How to use IAccessible Interface for providing coded UI support to a third party control?

Tags: winforms, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, dotnetbar

*I want to automate DotNetBar Controls using Coded UI*. I came across a forum,in which it was stated like **DotNetBar Controls supports Coded UI using IAccessible**
reference : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cda7dea-c3c5-497e-8185-2cefaef79283/cui-tests-for-devcomponentsdotnetbar-based-interface?forum=vsautotest
How to implement this. Could anyone please explain with a simple sample example?

Comment: If a control supports IAccessible then it should be seen by Coded UI (or UI Automation), so there's not much you have to do, it should work (if they *do* support IAccessibe)

Comment: @SimonMourier Could you please tell me how to use IAccessible interface for a control with a simple code example if possible?

Comment: You don't have to. Just use Coded Ui as you would do with any other control